# Bootstrap Icon is not visible

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to animate the refresh icon but my problem is icon is not visible in my jsp page .
Here is my markup ,

```
<a id="update" href="#"><i class="icon icon-refresh"></i></a>
```

and I used all links for bootstrap as

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Please can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon classes are renamed now

```
<a id="update" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8SRRN/)

Note: If you are using bootstrap.js then you need to include jQuery also before the bootstrap.js file

Comment: +1, Yes you are correct. Here is the plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAsNeLY5kx8MlGBjgwk8?p=preview

Comment: but I used same in other pages . . .

Comment: @user3377978 it is renamed in bootstrap 3.x... in 2.x it is `icon-x`

Answer (score 2):

The naming convension of bootstrap icons was rename from version 2.0 to 3.0

Please change

```
<i class="icon icon-refresh"></i>
```

to

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
```

The documentation for glyphicons in bootstrap 3.0 can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working for me

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
</body>
</html>
```